# How can I subset a list in R according to an index?

Tags: r, list

If I have a list in R:

```
list_test = list()
list_test[[1]] = 1
list_test[[2]] = 2
```

And I have an index

```
index_test = c(1,2)
```

How can I run `list_test[[index_test]]` to return a vector with 1 2? When I try to run this command I get the error:

```
Error in list_test[[index_test]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[[` in your case can only accept a length-1 vector (there are alternatives when `list_test` is *nested*, yours is not). I think you want `unlist(list_test[index_test])`.

```r
list_test = list()
list_test[[1]] = 1
list_test[[2]] = 2
index_test = c(1,2)
unlist(list_test[index_test])
# [1] 1 2
```

Refs:

- [`?[[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) (aka `?Extract` and `?[`).
- [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272)
- [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/3358272)

The expression `quux[[c(1, 2)]]` is equivalent to `quux[[1]][[2]]`. This is discussed in `?[[` as:

```
     ‘[[’ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single
     index ‘i’ is a vector of length ‘p’, ‘alist[[i]]’ is equivalent to
     ‘alist[[i1]]...[[ip]]’ providing all but the final indexing
     results in a list.
```

For example,

```r
quux <- list(1:3, 4:7)
str(quux)
# List of 2
#  $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
#  $ : int [1:4] 4 5 6 7
quux[[c(1, 2)]]
# [1] 2
quux[[1]][[2]] ## same thing
```

A deeper-nested option:

```r
quux <- list(list(1:3, 4:6), list(7:9, 10:13))
str(quux)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ : int [1:3] 4 5 6
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : int [1:3] 7 8 9
#   ..$ : int [1:4] 10 11 12 13
quux[[c(1, 2, 3)]]
# [1] 6
quux[[1]][[2]][[3]] ## same thing
```

Comment: @Tom, see an edit (with nested-list examples) posted after you accepted. Glad it helped!